# Unbind or undefine a variable in raku

Tags: raku, rakudo

After reading the Raku documentation, I only found [this](https://docs.raku.org/routine/undefine) for undefining a variable. I believe that in Raku there are differences between assignment and binding.

Defining and undefining a scalar is easy.

```
> my $n
(Any)
> $n.defined
False
> $n = 3
3
> $n.defined
True
> $n = Nil
(Any)
> $n.defined
False
```

When the variable is binded, it's not possible.

```
> my $k := 5
5
> $k := Nil
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Cannot use bind operator with this left-hand side
at line 2
------> <BOL>⏏<EOL>
> $k = Nil
Cannot assign to an immutable value
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

For arrays or hashes, I can empty it, but the variable is still defined.

For functions, when you define a function with `sub`, you cannot undefine it, but you can with an anonymous function.

```
> my &pera = -> $n { $n + 2}
-> $n { #`(Block|140640519305672) ... }
> &pera = Nil
(Callable)
> &pera.defined
False

> my &pera = -> $n { $n + 2}
-> $n { #`(Block|140640519305672) ... }
> &pera = Nil
(Callable)
> &pera.defined
False
> sub foo ($n) { $n + 1}
&foo
> &foo.defined
True
> &foo = Nil
Cannot modify an immutable Sub (&foo)
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

So what's the difference between assignment and binding?
How can I undefine a variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lots of different issues to discuss here.

```
> my $k := 5;
> $k := Nil;
Cannot use bind operator
```

This first problem is the Raku REPL. cf your last SO. Have you tried [CommaIDE](https://commaide.com/) or [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/raku)?

Your code is perfectly valid:

```
my $k := 5;
$k := Nil;
say $k; # Nil
```

---

Moving on:

```
my $k := 5;
$k = Nil;
Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

This is different. After binding `5` to `$k`, the `$k = Nil` code is attempting to *assign* a value into a *number*. Only containers<sup>**[1]**</sup> support *assignment*. A number isn't a container, so you can't assign into it.

---

Clarifying some cases you mentioned but didn't explicitly cover:

```
my @foo;
@foo := Nil;
Type check failed in binding; expected Positional...
```

While scalar variables (ones with a `$` sigil) will bind to any value or container, an `@` sigil'd variable will only bind to a `Positional` container such as an `Array`. (Likewise a `%` to an `Associative` such as a `Hash`.)

Not only that, but these containers are always defined. So they still return `True` for `.defined` even if they're empty:

```
my @foo := Array.new; # An empty array
say @foo.elems;       # 0 -- zero elements
say @foo.defined;     # True -- despite array being empty
```

Now assigning `Nil` to an array:

```
my @foo;
@foo = Nil;
say @foo; # [(Any)]
```

If a declaration of an `@` sigil'd variable doesn't bind it to some explicit `Positional` type it is instead bound to the *default* choice for an `@` variable. Which is an `Array` with a default element value of `Any`.

The `@foo = Nil;` statement above *assigns* a `Nil` value *into* the first element of `@foo`. The *assignment* of a value into a non-existing element of a multi-element container means a new `Scalar` container pops into existence and is bound to that missing element before assignment continues. And then, because we're assigning a `Nil`, and because a `Nil` denotes an *absence* of a value, the `Array`'s default value (`(Any)`) is copied into the `Scalar` instead of the `Nil`.

---

On to the `sub` case...

```
sub foo {}
&foo = {}  # Cannot modify an immutable Sub (&foo)
&foo := {} # Cannot use bind operator ...
```

While a `sub foo` declaration generates an `&foo` identifier, it is deliberately neither assignable nor bindable. If you want a `Callable` variable, you must declare one using ordinary variable declaration.

---

> Unbind or undefine a variable

You can't *un*bind variables in the sense of leaving them bound to nothing at all. (In other words, Raku avoids [the billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions).) In some cases you can *re*bind variables.

In some cases you can bind or assign an undefined value to a variable. If it's not a scalar variable then that's like the `@` variable example covered above. The scalar cases are considered next.

An example of the binding case:

```
my $foo := Any;
say $foo.defined;     # False
say $foo;             # (Any)
say $foo.VAR.WHAT;    # (Any)
```

We'll see what the `.VAR` is about in a moment.

The assignment case:

```
my $foo = Any;
say $foo.defined;     # False
say $foo.WHAT;        # (Any)
say $foo.VAR.WHAT;    # (Scalar)
```

It's important to understand that in this case the `$foo` is bound to a `Scalar`, which is a container, which is most definitely "defined", for some definition of "defined", despite appearances to the contrary in the `say $foo.defined;` line.

In the `say $foo.WHAT;` line the `Scalar` remains hidden. Instead we see an `(Any)`. But the `(Any)` is the type of the *value* held *inside* the `Scalar` container bound to `$foo`.

In the next line we've begun to pierce the veil by calling `.VAR.WHAT` on `$foo`. The `.VAR` gets the `Scalar` to reveal itself, rather than yielding the *value* it contains. And so we see the type `Scalar`.

But if you call `.defined` on that `Scalar` it *still* insists on hiding!:

```
my $foo;
say $foo.VAR.defined;  # False
say $foo.VAR.DEFINITE; # True
```

(The only way to force Raku to tell you the ultimate truth about its view of definiteness is to call the ultimate arbiter of definiteness, `.DEFINITE`.)

## So what are the rules?

The compiler will let you assign or bind a given new value or container to a variable, if doing so is valid according to the original variable declaration.

Assigning or binding an undefined value follows the same rules.

## Binding

All variables must be bound by the end of their declaration.

If a variable's declaration allows an undefined *value* to be bound/assigned to that variable, then the variable can be undefined in that sense. But in all other circumstances and senses variables themselves can never be "unbound" or "undefined".

Binding is about making a *variable* correspond to some *container* or *value*:

- Variables with `@` and `%` sigils must be bound to a *container* (default `Array` and `Hash` respectively).
- Variables with the `$` sigil must be bound to either a *container* (default `Scalar`) or a value.
- Variables with the `&` sigil must be bound to a `Callable` value or a `Scalar` constrained to contain a `Callable` value. (The `&` sigil'd variable that's visible as a consequence of declaring a `sub` does not allow rebinding or assignment.)

## Assignment

Assignment means *copying* a value *into* a container.

If a variable is bound to a container, then you can assign into it, provided the assignment is allowed by the compiler according to the original variable declaration.

If a variable is *not* bound to a container, then the compiler will reject an assignment to it.

## Scalar variables

If you use a scalar *container* as if it were a *value*, then you get the value that's held *inside* the container.

*Binding* a value (defined or undefined) to a scalar *variable* will mean it will stop acting as a container. If you then try to assign to that variable it won't work. You'd need to rebind it back to a container.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> In this answer I've used the word "container" to refer to any value that can serve as a container for containing other values. For example, instances of `Array`, `Hash`, or `Scalar`.